# Creating a dynamic CRUD UI in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to make a simple application to test out some CRUD code that we have written. I want the data entry UI to be built dynamically from the object that is being entered.

For e.g If its an ICustomer object which has properties for Name, collection of IOrders and some more properties. The definitions for these interface exist in a separate dll.

Could you please suggest me a good approach to use for achieving this? I can think of using Reflection to dynamically create the UI (through code instead of XAML). Would that be a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataForm` for `WPF` on `CodePlex`](http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/) that behaves similar to `DataForm` from **`The Silverlight Toolkit`**.

It auto-generates a data-entry form when you bind an object to it.

Comment: Thanks decyclone, But my object has also other custom objects and collections as properties. Will the DataForm be able to handle that?

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot? I have only used it for simple classes.